# Histogram Equalization without OpenCV

Tags: c++, visual-studio, image-processing, histogram

I'm writing an histogram equalization function, and I can't use OpenCV. My objective is to take the histogram of a grayscale image and equalize it to make it more clear. I'm using Visual Studio 2015.

This is the code I have so far:

```
void equalizeHistogram(int *pix, int nc, int nr)
{
    int cumhistogram[256];
    cumhistogram[0] = pix[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < 256; i++)
    {
        cout << pix[i];
        cumhistogram[i] = pix[i] + cumhistogram[i - 1];
    }

    int b[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        b[i] = (double)pix[i] / (nc*nr);
    }
    int c[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        c[i] = 0;
    }
    int d[256];

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        d[i] = round((double)cumhistogram[i] * (255 / (nr*nc)));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        c[d[i]] += b[i];
    }
    int finl[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        finl[i] = round(c[i] * 255);
}
```

I posted also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34125245/histogram-equalization-code). I posted a new question removing unnecessary information and code.

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34125245/histogram-equalization-code

Comment: OpenCV is open source, you might download it's source code and use it for inspiration

Comment: Since in my opinion your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34125245/histogram-equalization-code) question was _almost_ ok (just needed a little editing to remove unnecessary parts), I edited the relevant part of your code into this question, which otherwise look like a [gimme teh codez](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288133/is-using-stack-overflow-for-gimme-codez-questions-encouraged) question. For the future, please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/advice) before posting a new question.

Comment: Why does this question have a score of -3 (-2 after my vote)? This is not a bad question, and the question it's supposedly a duplicate of doesn't even exist anymore. Way to encourage new users, SO community. :V

Answer (score 5):

The function below will equalize the histogram of the input image. It's an adaptation from [OpenCV implementation](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/histogram.cpp).

Since you are using `int*` for the image, I kept this format (usually you would use `unsigned char*`, or `unsigned short*`). You can also pass the `max_val`, since for PGM images the range can be both in `[0,255]` or `[0,65535]`, depending on the image values.

If an image has an histogram like this:

[image]

the equalized histogram will be like:

[image]

```
void equalizeHistogram(int* pdata, int width, int height, int max_val = 255)
{
    int total = width*height;
    int n_bins = max_val + 1;

    // Compute histogram
    vector<int> hist(n_bins, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < total; ++i) {
        hist[pdata[i]]++;
    }

    // Build LUT from cumulative histrogram

    // Find first non-zero bin
    int i = 0;
    while (!hist[i]) ++i;

    if (hist[i] == total) {
        for (int j = 0; j < total; ++j) { 
            pdata[j] = i; 
        }
        return;
    }

    // Compute scale
    float scale = (n_bins - 1.f) / (total - hist[i]);

    // Initialize lut
    vector<int> lut(n_bins, 0);
    i++;

    int sum = 0;
    for (; i < hist.size(); ++i) {
        sum += hist[i];
        // the value is saturated in range [0, max_val]
        lut[i] = max(0, min(int(round(sum * scale)), max_val));
    }

    // Apply equalization
    for (int i = 0; i < total; ++i) {
        pdata[i] = lut[pdata[i]];
    }
}
```

Comment: Best answer! Although you could improve the speed immensely by using pointer instead of vector. Eg. int *hist = new int[hist_sz] {};

Comment: @SyaifulNizamYahya thanks. Regarding _"you could improve the speed immensely by using pointer ..."_ that's not true, they perform basically the same.

Comment: Inspired by your implementation, I did a 16bit grayscale histogram equalization here, https://github.com/syaifulnizamyahya/HistogramEqualization16Bit .